# PHP Timer usage

Tags: php, timer

Firstly, I want to echo text and ,after 5 seconds,I want to echo another text.
So I write...

```
<?php

echo 'Text';
flush();

sleep(5);

flush();
echo 'Another Text';


?>
```

But I see both of (Text Another Text ) after 5 seconds.How can I do for this?

Comment: For intervals and timers it would be better to use javascript. Is this possible for you?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation

> Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser.

So you see both `TextAnother Text`together.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Answer (score 0):

Have you started output buffering at some time? If so, you need to use [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to flush.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off output buffering if you have it on or call ob_flush() too. Any output compressing (like gzip) will also mess it up. If it doesn't work try modifying these two php.ini directives to:

output_buffering = off

zlib.output_compression = off